# Can Haskell pretend to be a database, and if so, how?

Tags: database, sqlite, haskell, acid

I realise that this might be a silly question, but is there any way to get Haskell (or use some library with Haskell) to get it to act like an SQL database? If so, how?

Something like SQLite, but without persistence?

The idea is that I could create Haskell "tables" and Haskell "indexes" (stored in memory) and an external application could query them.

It's okay if it can't handle joins.

The reason is that an external application needs to query a database, but I'd like to keep my data in [acid-state](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state), and don't want to do the intermediate step of dumping stuff to the database all the time.

Comment: Yes, Haskell can do that. :)  If your question was actually "how?", then the answer is much more complicated.

Comment: This is straightforward. But you need to pick a protocol, and a transport, and then design an API. JSON over HTTP (possibly with RESTful URLs) is a relatively straightforward choice.

Comment: http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/03/history-of-persistence

Comment: Keep in mind I don't want Haskell to connect to a SQL database, I want the Haskell program to be the SQL database.

Comment: If you want to parse realistic sql in your queries, consider this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hssqlppp, and if you want to do drop-in interop, consider writing a backend using the existing packages for either cassandra or mongo...

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask why you need to do this... :P

Comment: Andres F: Last sentence of the question says why.

Answer (score 2):

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ixset/1.0.3/doc/html/Data-IxSet.html

Answer (score 2):

> The idea is that I could create Haskell "tables" and Haskell "indexes" (stored in memory) and an external application could query them.

Sure, no matter what programming language you use, in your application you could expose an interface (probably via sockets or the like) to construct and query data.

Comment: I haven't heard of any implementations of a SQL-like language in Haskell, but there are mechanisms for constructing relational data collections and querying them (Via `acid-state` and `ixset` for example).